# Why Mysql dont used index on WHERE clause using OR?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

First of all i have the following table structures.

```
Table Document
  ## DocID ##  ## DocName## ## DuplicateID ##
      1              Doc1        null
      2              Doc2        null
      3              Doc3        null
      4              Doc4         1

Table FolderTree
  ## FolderID ##  ## MemberDocID ##
       1                1
       1                2
       1                3
```

I have index on `DocID, DuplicateID and MemberDocID and FolderID`

My Query is this :

```
SELECT d.* 
from Document d, FolderTree f 
WHERE (d.DocID = f.MemberDocID or d.DuplicateID = f.MemberDocID) and f.FolderID = 1 
GROUP BY d.DocID ;
```

So basically i want to retrieve all documents from Folder with id 1 and also its duplicate documents from the table. The group by is used to maintain uniqueness of record that no document will be retrieve twice.

This query is working fine but in large volume of records it getting slower.Here is the explain output.

---

```
| select type | table | type | possible_keys | key    | rows  |   extra         |

   simple        d     range   PRIMARY,...    PRIMARY   83168   Using temporary..
   simple        f     All     DuplicateIDInx Null      108787  Using join buffer
```

What concerns me is that the table f does not use the index on DuplicateID.
My question is, Why is it so? Can somebody enlighten me on this matter.
Im using Mysql 5.x
Thanks :)

Comment: Rewrite the query to use `UNION` - it's a common trick to avoid ORs (which are not optimized well)

Comment: I've already read about it, is there another alternative? Union is not supported in hibernate and i want these to convert into hql later. :)

Comment: Check the query posted. You have `d.DuplicateID = f.MemberID` but you mention no `MemberID` in table `f`. I suppose that is a typo.

Comment: thats MemberDocID sorry type. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM Document d 
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM FolderTree f 
        WHERE ( d.DocID = f.MemberDocID OR d.DuplicateID = f.MemberDocID )
          AND f.FolderID = 1 
      ) ;
```

and this one (edited):

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS FolderID
     ) AS Parameter
  CROSS JOIN 
     Document d 
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM FolderTree f 
        WHERE f.MemberDocID = d.DocID
          AND f.FolderID = Parameter.FolderID
      ) 
   OR EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM FolderTree f 
        WHERE f.MemberDocID = d.DuplicateID
          AND f.FolderID = Parameter.FolderID
      ) ;
```

I would also add a compound (composite) index on `FolderTree (FolderID, MemberDocID)`.

If you haven't already an index on `Document (DuplicateID)`, add one as well.

The extra requirement could probably be better solved by writing the query in a stored procedure with a parameter.

Comment: Is it possible to move the f.FolderID = 1 outside of the exists subquery?

Comment: Why do you want to move it out of there?

Comment: For a very crucial reason :). But is it possible to move it out to reference it from FolderTree? Thanks

Comment: No I don't see how it can be out. The `FolderID` is in `FolderTree` table only.

Comment: Do you mean to have it in the query once (as a parameter)?

Comment: I have a another problem, i want to know make the the return of EXISTS as parameter so that i can check in the succeding sub selects. Is it possible to make it as parameter? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

looks like proper indexes are not there. can you clarify more on the table structure and query.

1. about f.MemberID column used in query at "or d.DuplicateID = f.MemberID"
2. explain shows DuplicateIDInx index name in table FolderTree. can you mention exact index defination from tables.

Comment: the DuplicateIDinx is the index of DuplicateID in Document table. No index type used. Im using innodDB engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an in clause instead and use distinct instead of group by.

```
SELECT distinct d.* 
from Document d
join FolderTree f on f.MemberDocID in (d.DocID, d.DuplicateID)
WHERE f.FolderID = 1
```

According to [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e631f/1/2), this hasn't changed much, besides making the join explicit.

If you change your `duplicateid`, however

```
update document
set duplicateid = docid
where duplicateid is null
```

and select on `duplicateid` only

```
SELECT distinct d.* 
from Document d
join FolderTree f on f.MemberDocID = d.DuplicateID
WHERE f.FolderID = 1
```

will use the index on `duplicateid`